# Windows setting to run services faster

Tags: windows-10, services, performance-tuning

I run several server and processing tasks on my computer while I'm away.  I found a setting builtin to Windows 10 once to optimize for background programs, not regular applications.  For the life of me, I can't find it.

Where is setting to optimize for behind the scenes programs?

Comment: This setting increases the background/foreground ratio, but if you aren't there is no significant foreground load and the background processes will have all the CPU to themselves, whatever the setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Settings, System, About.  System info.  Advanced sysyem settings.  Advanced tab.

There is a setting there "Choose how to allocate processor resources."  set to Background services

Is that what you wanted?